# Internet Explorer Slow throughout whole Network

Tags: networking, dns, internet-explorer

Currently I'm facing a very strange Behaviour. I know, that Internet Explorer might be *slightly* slower than it's competitors, but i used to use it for various reasons.

However at the moment it is impossible:

IE is taking VERY long to resolve a hostname. About 30 seconds PER hostname. Loading Facebook with all the foreign servers involved takes about 3 Minutes to finish.

Chrome and Firefox are working as expected - split second.

The *strange* thing is: The IE Issue does NOT apply for all websites. Some are loading as expected. Pages where i noted this very slow behaviour are:

- facebook
- google (starting with the main search page, Search-as-you-type is a nightmare)
- youtube
- various MS-Sites like technet, msdna etc.

Strange behaviour continues. This Issues does apply for:

- IE 11 on Windows 8
- IE 11 on Windows Server 2012
- IE 11 on Windows 7
- **DOES NOT APPLY:** IE 11 on a Windows 7 Notebook (same Version as the Desktop uses)

it's about the very same set of sites...

Things I tried:

- Disable Proxy-Auto-Configuration
- Reset IE.
- Use Google DNS directly.
- Restart DNS-Server, Router
- Fullscan for Maleware
- Run IE without Addons (Save-Mode)
- Reinstall IE (add/remove from windows features)

It seems related to the latest Version of Internet Explorer. However, I cannot find something on the internet, neither does it apply for all websites.

At the moment i'm absolutely out of ideas where to start..

ps.: I have my own local DNS server(s), so i first thought, that Chrome and FF might use other DNS servers directly and thats the cause - but even if i completely disable my own DNS Servers, reset the cache and provide the google-dns directly, the issue is present.

I'm pretty sure it's just about the DNS-Resolving. Once a certain hostname responds, downloads are fast as it should be. (but up to 45 seconds to start)

---

I noted, that Outlook has some troubles connecting to my exchange servers as well... So, it *seems* like there is *some* setting -which MS-Products are using - that are slowing progress down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS IE likes to follow all security rules where firefox and chrome does not.

This could be due only on https sites, but Try below steps from IE 11.

**Tools > Internet Options > Advanced >**

Look for Security 
**Uncheck** below.

**"Check for Publisher's Certificate revocation"
"Check for server certificate revocatoin"**

**Also** Go to Tools > Compatibility View Settings
**Uncheck**

**"Use Microsoft Compatibility Lists"**

Let me know if this helped or not.

Comment: Bam! Unchecked "Check for Publisher's Certificate revocation" "Check for server certificate revocatoin" and "Enable SmartScreen-Filter" - For now it seems to be about 2000% percent faster! will evaluate... (From time to time it is just "good" without changing anything) and then accept the answer!

Comment: The mentioned Notebook which does not show this behaviour on IE 11 is part of another domain, where all security settings are disabled by GPO... So it *seems* like you got a jackpot there.

Comment: After few days of testing I can confirm: Problems are gone. If i find some time the next days i'll try to reenable those settings one by one to figure out the actual problem. I believe its the cert revocation check.